# CSS Frame Image over another image to create a painting like effect

Tags: css, background, image

i have from the Website Designer the follwoing result : http://mp-books.ru/html/img/result_03.jpg

The ideea is that the stamp-like frame will remain on the page, but the person picture will change from case to case, will be take from the database.

I have arrived at this result : http://jsfiddle.net/alexpeta/MUpk8/1/ but thats the best i can do.

I have experimented with rotate like

```
-webkit-transform: rotate(-18deg); 
    -moz-transform: rotate(-18deg); 
    transform:rotate(-18deg); 
    -o-transform:rotate(-18deg);
```

but IE will not allow this transformation becuse it has Filter with an exact number of degrees : eg: 45, 90, 180 etc... and the customer wants the pic titled in each browser.

Any help on this brain-buster?

Regards,
Alex

Comment: Do you have access to a server-side technology? Since you are pulling pictures from a database anyways, this is probably more appropriately done on the server.

Comment: yes, i am the developer lol, but i am making for this site the CSS as well, and im not that good at it. the platform is on IIS with ASP.Net 3.5 framework

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a [MATRIX](http://www.useragentman.com/IETransformsTranslator/doc.html) transformation on the image

```
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Matrix(sizingMethod='auto expand',
    M11=0.951, M12=0.309,
    M21= -0.309, M22=0.951);
```

would correspond to 18 degrees

The calculations:

```
[cos(18)  sin(18)]
[-sin(18) cos(18)]
```

Comment: thank you, how can i get these numbers? i mean, how do u calculate them? what is the algoritm?

Comment: yup got it. its sin() and cos() of tetha, which is in radians not degrees. so first change get radians  = PI * degress / 360. and then use cos() and sin() for that. i will try it now

Comment: arg I'm a math major I should have know XP Sorry my linear algebra is a bit rusty.

Answer (score 2):

The best solution for compatibility would be to transform the image on the server side using [System.Drawing](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.image.aspx). As for the frame overlay, I think you're over-complicating things: if you know what the background will always look like, don't cut the frame out as a transparent image, cut it out with the background in it so it hides any overflow from the picture.

Comment: thanks Tom, i will try with System.Drawing to see if it works. the background is complex however : http://mp-books.ru/html/img/bgpagina2.jpg and if i will make the page fluid i am not sure if the page will be fluid it will work. will test it though.

Comment: Ah, good point on the background. You can just crop the image when you rotate it if need be.

Comment: System.Drawing is definitely the way to go on this.  It'll guarantee the same image appears in every browser.

Answer (score 1):

The CSS transform property allows developers to rotate, scale, and skew blocks of HTML via CSS. Although you can do the same thing with images in Photoshop or The GIMP, using CSS transforms allows developers to do the same thing with any HTML markup and allows users to select the text within the transformed object.
[checkout this solution](http://www.useragentman.com/blog/2010/03/09/cross-browser-css-transforms-even-in-ie/)

Comment: thank you for the response. i will do further reading on this, and maybe this will be the answer. if i will make it work, i`ll mark it and buy you a beer. cheers